# pattern to match multiple filenames with find utility

Tags: regex, find

How to find multiple filenames with the bash find command?

```
$ find /path/* -type f -name pattern
```

The pattern should match a list of file names:

- fname1.jpg
- fname2.png
- myfile.css
- example.gif

I tryed with

https://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/linux-find-multiple-filenames-patterns-command-example
find multiple filenames command: finding three filename extensions

```
find . -type f \( -name "*cache" -o -name "*xml" -o -name "*html" \)
```

and it works.

Anyway I think it would be cleaner with a -name pattern, rather than with a list of -names.

from 
$ man find

```
   -name pattern
```

I m searching for something like: -name '[fname2.png|myfile.css|example.gif ]'

Comment: I believe command which you have shown is good enough to show all kind of format files in a directory(whatever format we mention in command as you shown too), could you please do let me know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Using two backslashes is wrong: it escapes a backslash, but you want to escape the `(` from the shell. Use only one backslash and it will work.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes that command woks but I m searching something like  -name '[fname2.png|myfile.css|example.gif ]'

Comment: @Jens sorry you are right  I have corrected the question ... I double escaped to post here  ... but isnt necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-regex` alternative would look as follows:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(jpg|png|css)$"
```

---

As for `-name` option:

> `-name pattern` - Base of file name (the path with the leading
>   directories removed) matches **shell** pattern.

*Shell* pattern is not a full-fledged *regex* pattern.

Comment: thanks for the answer @RomanPerekhrest ... why is it not possible to put the regexp as an argument of -name?

Comment: @SimoneBonelli, from `man find`: *`-name pattern`
              Base of file name (the path with the leading directories removed) matches **shell** pattern pattern.* . Shell pattern is not a full-fledged regex pattern

Answer (score 0):

Just mix them:

```
find -name "aoc*" -regextype awk -regex ".*[0-9].(class|scala)"
```

This searches for files, matching shell-pattern aoc* and end in number, with ending .class or .scala.

For your example:

```
find -name "fname*" -regextype awk -regex ".*[0-9].(png|jpg|css)"
```

Available types are listet with:

```
find -regextype -help
```

However, I first tried "-regextype sed" which is available, but sed itself has options, changing the styles of regexes. And patterns I used to use with sed didn't work, but since the pattern works with awk, it's sufficient for me.